# cant import python module I just made on github

Tags: python, github, pip, package, setuptools

I want to learn how to make my own collection of functions available to myself and my coworkers. After some reading I settled on making a `python package`, putting it on `github` and using `pip install git+https://` to make it available to my coworkers. We use `anaconda` by the way, not sure if it matters.

So I've made the following repository: https://github.com/accountname/reponame and in a fresh anaconda environment using:

```
conda create -n github_test python=3.9
```

I will install my package into it using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/accountname/reponame.git
```

This worked! Great! When I run `conda list`  I get the following output:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\envs\github_test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           haa95532_4
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39haa95532_2
openssl                   1.1.1m               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       21.2.4           py39haa95532_0
python                    3.9.7                h6244533_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py39haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.37.2               h2bbff1b_0
testing                   0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2021e                hda174b7_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py39haa95532_2
```

To test it out I decided to open python and import the new package:

```
(github_test) C:\Users\MyName>python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'
>>>
```

Importing any of the other modules on the list by the name on the list does work. So I'm thinking my setup.py file is missing some information.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='testing',
    version='0.0.1',
    url='https://github.com/accountname/reponame',
    author='My Name',
    author_email='REDACTED',
    description='testing123',
    install_requires=[]
)
```

I figure this would only work with a public repository. Ideally I would love to be able to use a private repository with this installation and distribution method. Any ideas?

Edits:

- Removed my personal information
- "Any ideas?" --> You can just point to a private repo and login using the prompt. Man what a time to be alive :D

Comment: The `setuptools.setup` call in `setup.py` seems to be missing a [`packages` parameter](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html). So you are distributing an empty Python project without any importable package. You probably need either `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` or `packages=['testing']`.

Comment: You may want to remove your email address from the question...

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb good idea thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setuptools.setup` call in `setup.py` seems to be missing a [`packages` parameter](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html). So you are distributing an empty Python project without any importable package. You probably need either `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` or `packages=['testing']`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for taking the time to help me out!